# What's the meaning of "expansive trim package"?

Tags: trim

When I read a house description, there is this line "Features include: expansive trim package, granite, tile, hardwoods, french doors". Can anyone help me on "expansive trim package", what is it?

Comment: If you haven't figured it out by now, I'm about to set you straight: realtors are full of hot air. (Or something less complimentary that wouldn't be fit for SE.) "Expansive" could be a misspelling, a reference to nice trim (as @Jack noted below), a tip of the hat to the fact that they managed to find some 1-5/8" buck a mile casing for cheap and did the whole house in it, or possibly that the trim is made of magic sponge that expands when you hit it with water. Go look and the house and see what you think.

Answer (score 3):

I would expect it to mean more than just simple baseboards, door and window trim.

This may include crown moldings, wainscoting, perhaps even a 3 piece base instead of one or two piece, chair rail or maybe even a more elaborate trim around windows and doors.

Comment: I agree that it should include those things, however I think its more of a generic answer by the realtor/listor to say they put some upgrades in for the trim level.. don't expect all those things.

Comment: I should have detailed the answer better, I did not mean to imply all the items would be included, I pictured more on an ala carte basis.